# Flexible search Query for stringset?

Tags: mysql, sql, sap-commerce-cloud

Please find the below query:

Table Name : B

query : select * from {B}

```
ID  comp  
1   d,e,f
```

I want to check if the value `'f'` is present in `comp`, or not, using an SQL/Flexible search Query.

Is it possible to write a sql query for this scenario?

Update :

```
SELECT  DISTINCT {b:pk}  FROM {A AS a left join B as B on {a:ncode} = {b:ncode} and {a:qCode}  =  {b:qCode}}

WHERE 

{a:compID} IN ()
```

Assume `a:compID` is `"f"`

What should be my subquery after the `IN` operator to achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 1):

You can search in string in mysql:

//full search:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE comp LIKE '%f%'
```

// start with f

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE comp LIKE '%f'
```

// end with f

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE comp LIKE 'f%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM {B} where {comp} LIKE '%,f,%'
```

Comment: While this code may solve the OP's question, it's better to add context, or explain why your code should solve the problem. In this way, future visitors can learn, and apply it to their own issues. Quality Answers are more likely to be upvoted, and compete answers keep the SO platform high quality.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
 SELECT FIND_IN_SET('f',(SELECT comp FROM t));
```

[Run this code on Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/si2o3QJWDT6FST1TR2LVXm/0)

If you want to check present or not present then:

```
SELECT case when FIND_IN_SET('f',(SELECT comp FROM t))=0 then'not present'
          else 'present' end from dual;
```

Comment: Above query wont work in my case as i am using hybris flexible search query

Answer (score 0):

Start with f
`LIKE 'f%'`

End with f
`LIKE '%f'`

Answer (score 0):

Query need to be updated as below.

We shouldn't use IN in this case.

SELECT  DISTINCT {b:pk}  FROM {A AS a left join B as B on {a:ncode} = {b:ncode} and {a:qCode}  =  {b:qCode}}

WHERE

**{a:compID} LIKE '%f%'**